# Pandas заменить в столбцах даты на значение 0

Tags: python, pandas

Занимаюсь очисткой данных. Встретился столбец в котором перемешаны и целые числа и даты. Дата имеет формат `день.месяц` (`04.сен 17.фев` и т.д). Нужно заменить данные значения на 0.

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь методом [to_numeric(..., errors='coerce')](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html).

Пример:

```
In [40]: df
Out[40]:
             col
0             33
1         04.сен
2             12
3         17.фев
4             45
5             56
6  просто строка

In [41]: df['col'] = pd.to_numeric(df['col'], errors='coerce').fillna(0).astype(int)

In [42]: df
Out[42]:
   col
0   33
1    0
2   12
3    0
4   45
5   56
6    0
```

Answer (score 0):

Можете воспользоваться [стандартной функцией replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html).

```
df['YourColumn'].replace(['04.сен 17.фев'], ['0']) 
date = ['04.сен 17.фев', '05.сен 17.фев', '06.сен 17.фев']
```

Для случая, когда у нас есть несколько дат:

```
date = ['04.сен 17.фев', '05.сен 17.фев', '06.сен 17.фев']
df['YourColumn'].replace(date, ['0'])
```

Comment: Дат слишком много. Вручную вводит в replace() трудоёмко слишком.

Comment: @Pecherni В цикле перебрать? Даты же известные заранее?